# Change image size with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm trying to change the size of an image with JavaScript. The jS file is separate from the HTML page.

I want to set the height and width of an image in the JS file. Any good ways on doing this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Once you have a reference to your image, you can set its height and width like so:

```
var yourImg = document.getElementById('yourImgId');
if(yourImg && yourImg.style) {
    yourImg.style.height = '100px';
    yourImg.style.width = '200px';
}
```

In the html, it would look like this:

```
<img src="src/to/your/img.jpg" id="yourImgId" alt="alt tags are key!"/>
```

Comment: You have to make sure the javascript is executed after the page is finished loading.  You can either do this by putting it in an onload event, or putting the script at the bottom of your page, just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Is there any way to change the actual height `yourImage.height = 100` after the style change and not have the image cropped?

Comment: Sure, if you want to readjust only one dimension later on, and maintain the aspect ratio of the image, you can use `auto` for the value you're not explicitly setting (e.g. `yourImg.style.height = '500px'` and `yourImg.style.width = 'auto'`).  Here's a quick example I put together: http://codepen.io/patheard/pen/aEwfn

Comment: @Pat so we can put it in the onload event ;) <body  onload="MyFunction()"

Comment: @Pat In my opinion no need (if condition) a browser has 2 options (Supports Javascript / Not Supports) i think there is no option 3

Answer (score 22):

You can change the actual width/height attributes like this:

```
var theImg = document.getElementById('theImgId');
theImg.height = 150;
theImg.width = 150;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if the image's width and height were set via CSS

Answer (score 11):

If you want to resize an image after it is loaded, you can attach to the `onload` event of the `<img>` tag. Note that it may not be supported in all browsers ([Microsoft's reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535259.aspx) claims it is part of the HTML 4.0 spec, but the [HTML 4.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) doesn't list the `onload` event for `<img>`).

The code below is tested and working in: IE 6, 7 & 8, Firefox 2, 3 & 3.5, Opera 9 & 10, Safari 3 & 4 and Google Chrome:

```
<img src="yourImage.jpg" border="0" height="real_height" width="real_width"
    onload="resizeImg(this, 200, 100);">

<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeImg(img, height, width) {
    img.height = height;
    img.width = width;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Changing an image is easy, but how do you change it back to the original size after it has been changed? You may try this to change all images in a document back to the original size:

```
var i,L=document.images.length;
for(i=0;i<L;++i){
 document.images[i].style.height = 'auto'; //setting CSS value
 document.images[i].style.width = 'auto'; //setting CSS value
// document.images[i].height = ''; (don't need this, would be setting img.attribute)
// document.images[i].width = ''; (don't need this, would be setting img.attribute)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[you can see the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOCJz.png)
In these simple block of code you can change the size of your image ,and make it bigger when the mouse enter over the image , and it will return to its original size when mouve leave.

**html:**

```
<div>
<img  onmouseover="fifo()" onmouseleave="fifo()" src="your_image"   
       width="10%"  id="f" >
</div>
```

**js file:**

```
var b=0;
function fifo() {
       if(b==0){
            document.getElementById("f").width = "300";
           b=1;
          }
       else
          {
         document.getElementById("f").width = "100";
          b=0;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Direct manipulation

HTML tag declaration for image:

```html
<img id="my-img" src="src/to/your/image.jpg" width="1280px" height="720px" />
<!-- OR -->
<img id="my-img" src="src/to/your/image.jpg" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px;" />
```

Handling html tag by direct access to object image:

```js
const myImg = document.getElementById("my-img");

// Set a new width and height
myImg.style.width = "800px";
myImg.style.height = "450px";
// Or set a new width and height by attribute
// This option is not advisable because the attribute has a 
// low priority over the style property.
myImg.setAttribute("width", 800);
myImg.setAttribute("height", 450);
```

## Functions for manipulation

Using the `updateImageSizeWithWidth` or `updateImageSizeWithHeight` method below, you can increase or decrease any image without having to explicitly specify the exact width and height, you only need one value out of these two to update the image size.

```js
/**
 * Update image size using width
 *
 * param {HTMLImageElement} img
 * param {number} newWidth
 */function updateImageSizeWithWidth(img, newWidth) {
  // Getting the width and height of the current image 
  const oldWidth =  Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(img).width || img.getAttribute("width"));
  const oldHeight = Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(img).height || img.getAttribute("height"));
  // Getting proportional height with new width
  const newHeight = (newWidth * oldHeight)/oldWidth;
  // Setting dimensions in the image
  img.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
  img.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
}

/**
 * Update image size using height
 *
 * param {HTMLImageElement} img
 * param {number} newHeight
 */
function updateImageSizeWithHeight(img, newHeight) {
  // Getting the width and height of the current image 
  const oldWidth =  Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(img).width || img.getAttribute("width"));
  const oldHeight = Number.parseFloat(getComputedStyle(img).height || img.getAttribute("height"));
  // Getting proportional height with new width
  const newWidth = (newHeight * oldWidth)/oldHeight;
  // Setting dimensions in the image
  img.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
  img.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
}

updateImageSizeWithWidth(myImg, 800);
// Or
updateImageSizeWithHeight(myImg, 450);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//  This one has print statement so you can see the result at every stage if     you would like.  They are not needed

function crop(image, width, height)
{
    image.width = width;
    image.height = height;
    //print ("in function", image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    return image;
}

var image = new SimpleImage("name of your image here");
//print ("original", image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
//crop(image,200,300);
print ("final", image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

Comment: Try describing what you're doing in your answers, instead of just pasting naked source code. It almost invariably helps the asker a lot more if you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- .html file:

```html
<img src="src/to/your/img.jpg" id="yourImgId"/>
```

- .js file:

```
document.getElementById("yourImgId").style.height = "heightpx";
```

The same you can do with the width.