# Javascript - trying to locate an image

Tags: javascript

I am not expert in javascript, so, excuse my lack of knowledge.

I am trying to interact with an image on a page on the web, to create some automation.

I need to click on that image using javascript, from a script.

I did everything to discover how to access that image and no success at all. The image is not responding to anything. I suppose I am not reaching the right object.

Trying to discover the object, I created a very simple script, that will scale every image on that page, to see at least if I can reach all img object.

This is the script

```
for (i=0;i<=100;i++) {
document.image[i].width.value = '300';
}
```

No changes at all.

Is the script correct? is that anything that may be preventing the image to respond from external scripts?

Any clues? thanks.

___ EDIT

the image I need to click is declared like this:

```
 <div class="leaderboard-text">
          <span id="addon-add-language-button"><image class="ajaxListAddButtonEnabled" listId="localizationList" src="/itc/images/blue-add-language-button.png"><image class="ajaxListAddButtonDisabled" listId="localizationList" style="display:none;" src="/itc/images/blue-add-language-button-disabled.png"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: This provides succinct answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript

Comment: Can you provide more detail regarding *what* you want to do with which image object?

Comment: @hjhndr unfortunately the images have no id

Comment: @Tomalak I need to know how to access the image, because I need to click it using javascript.

Comment: I have added more informations on the code, on how the image I need to click is declared.

Comment: Why do you need to click it? Usually you can trigger the JavaScript action you want to happen without having to emulate a mouse click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an 's' in images and some other things.

```
for (i=0, lughez = document.images.length; i<lughez ; i++) {
    document.images[i].width= '300';
}
```

but if the image has an id you could do:

```
document.getElementById('id').click()
```

to click your image where 'id' is the id you are using

Comment: I think `i<=lughez` should be `i<lughez` ?

Comment: unfortunately the images have no id. I have added more informations to the question to show how the image (I need to reach) is declared.

Comment: There is no consistent support for `click()`, so this solution is not recommendable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `document.image`, there is `document.images`

```
for (var i=0, l=document.images.length; i<l; i++) {
  var ing = document.images[i];
  img.width = 300; // but why do you want all images to be equal width?
}
```

Comment: you have a typo: it's not ing

Comment: 300 is just to know if I am reaching the images with the code, just to see a dramatic change.

Comment: @DigitalRobot: I see. I'd use CSS (as in `img.style.border = '1px solid red'`) for such a case, this is less destructive for the page layout.