# iOS / Android HTML javascript camera decrease picture size

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I'm using a fairly standard `<input type='file'/>` on an IOS & Android device. If I select browse it would let me take a picture with the camera & upload it.

The issue I'm having is with the average sizes of these jpegs is massive (~1.4 mb each), especially uploading over a 3G connection. Is there a way to make them smaller using javascript or something before uploading them?

Comment: How much smaller? I'm pretty sure there is a way to get the thumbnail of an image in iOS, I did it in an app that I wrote.

Comment: perhaps to something under 200kb?, not too small but visible for others to see on their mobile devices, its meant for a mobile picture feed

Comment: Similar question:  [Change Image Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)