# Set image size using logo-selector liferay

Tags: liferay

How to set image size when using **liferay-ui:logo-selector** as

```
<liferay-ui:logo-selector
defaultLogoURL='<%=themeDisplay.getPathImage() + "/organization_logo?img_id=0"%>'
editLogoURL="<%=editOrganizationLogoURL%>" imageId="<%=logoId%>"
logoDisplaySelector=".organization-logo" showBackground="<%=false%>" />
```

I just can't get it done.I can change image size while displaying logo using **img html tag**.

Comment: I don't think so you can do this with `<liferay-ui:logo-selector>` it does not set the height and width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rasabihariKumar mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757182/set-image-size-using-logo-selector-liferay#comment22400025_15757182), it is not possible to set the image size i.e. the `height` or `width` of the logo through `<liferay-ui:logo-selector>`.

1. One thing you can do is upload the logo with the correct dimensions
2. or else extend the `<liferay-ui:logo-selector>` tag through a hook or ext so that you can send the image `width` and `height` to the tag.
3. Or you can change the image size through javascript after the whole page is loaded through javascript. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297456/468763) may help you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and i too found out that <liferay-ui:logo-selector> doesn't contains attribute for custom css...i am marking this question as my answer on basis of point 1 and 2....