# Making css changes just with a post tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tumblr

I'm making a Tumblr theme.

Is there any way to change the width of an image from 25% to 50% only if the image post has a specific tag like "big" or "double" ?

This is what I have:

The CSS:

```
   .post {
        width:25%
   }

   .big {
       width:50%
   }
```

The HTML:

```
   {block:Posts}

          {block:Photo}

                 <div class="post {block:HasTags}{block:ifTaggedBig}big{/block:ifTaggedBig}{/block:HasTags}"> 
                      <img src="..." /> 
                 </div>

           {/block:Photo}

     {/block:Posts}
```

Comment: what's the html structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This would be possible, but I feel your question would yield better results if you expand on it. Show the markup for a post, etc.

Comment: updated with the markup @mikedidthis

Comment: @user2946744 Answered, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### Altering a layout with Post Tags

First, we need to modify the theme mark up, adding a variable named: `{TagsAsClasses}`

```
{block:Posts}
    {block:Photo}
    <div class="post {TagsAsClasses}"> 
        <img src="..." /> 
    </div>
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
```

Then use the following CSS:

```
.post img {
    width:25%
}
.big img {
    width:50%
}
```

Finally tag your post as `big`. This will result in the following markup being generated:

```
<div class="post big"> 
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Ref: *Post Variables* http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: Didn't know the "{TagAsClasses}" command. Thank you very much @mikedidthis

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can locate the post/image using the tag (if not, you would need to provide more information on how you're storing the data), try [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)