# How to change image height and width with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="Poppen" style="float: right">
     <script language="JavaScript">
            function random_imglink(){
               var myimages=new Array()
               //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
               myimages[1]="Kleren/Kleren1.jpg"
               myimages[2]="Kleren/Kleren2.jpg"
               myimages[3]="Kleren/Kleren3.jpg"
               myimages[4]="Kleren/Kleren4.jpg"
               myimages[5]="Kleren/Kleren5.jpg"

               //specify corresponding links below
               var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
               if (ry==0)
                 ry=1
                 document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
            }
            random_imglink()
           //-->
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a javascript code to change my images when the page is refreshed 
But those images are too large and I can't find how to make them smaller?

Comment: Incidentally, you could simplify your script if your image names keep that convention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change image size with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use height and width attributes

> height="xx" width="xx"

add those attr at

```
document.write('<img src=myimages[ry] width=xx height=xx> border=0>')
```

for more info check the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)

Comment: Thanks it worked! :D Do you eventually know how I can align it more to the right? It's now like this http://prntscr.com/2y85z2

Comment: You don't have to use both the height and the width. If you specify just one the other will be inferred based on the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: I know, but I fail at getting the bottom image next to the upper image

Answer (score 0):

In your img tag you can add the attr height and width. You can change the xxx into 50px or whatever height and width.

```
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0 style="height:xxx;width:xxx;">')
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.height="50px";
```

Or simple css.

```
#Poppen img {width: 100px; height:100px;}
```