# HTML or Javascript button to change picture size or cell (containing picture) size

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be the simplest way to show a picture, but also allow the user a choice of preset buttons to display the picture at alternative sizes?  (note, source photo still shown, just redrawn on the fly at different sizes)

I thought perhaps either if its possibly to dynamically set the size of a table cell with photo contained within, or perhaps a better Javascript alternative?

Comment: Please try to edit your question and fix the image tag, currently you failed to upload it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Answers / examples:

http://home.comcast.net/~urbanjost/resize/resize.html

[Change image size with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

http://ibnelson.com/jQuery/ch03/width2.html

Problem solved :)