# how can i combine javascript variables inside html

Tags: javascript, html

i was wondering how to change a picture's size with a dynamic variable, but i cant make it work for some reason. here is my code:

i have a variable named picH inside my javascript block:

> var picH = 2;

and then i have my html code which supplies the image with the height property:

> img src="img/1.png" height="picH"

I tried to supply the variable but it doesn't seem to work. the size does change if i enter a number instead.

Comment: you have no idea what you are doing - how about reading up some basics on html and js

Comment: You need to read through some beginner JS tutorials. JS doesn't work in the way you currently believe, i.e. just putting variable names in HTML. You need to reference elements via something called DOM scripting.

Comment: Check out angularJS. This will allow you to include JS inside your HTML with {{}} syntax. Or Handlebars.js. There is a lot to choose from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change image size with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

Comment: @WesDuff that's a poor suggestion. Nothing against angular but you don't need a library to change an images height, or to just use inline scripting.

Comment: @WesDuff I think that might be a little complex for what this person needs. if we are recommending libraries for beginners, which we probably shouldn't be, jQuery is much simpler for beginners, though it doesn't set up as much foundation. OP, you need to study JS and how it interacts with the DOM more.

Comment: Wow guys. Let's give this ghost some help instead of being all rude and stuff eh?

Comment: True but what is the best way to learn? I say by trial and fire! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first off as sad as it may be, I agree with the mean comments above that you should probably just read a few HTML and JavaScript tutorials. jQuery is probably a good way to go but believe it or not back in the olden days we used JavaScript without the benefit of fancy frameworks. I'd say what you're driving at is something a little more like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/1.png" id="theIDofTheImage">
    </body>
</html> 

<script>
    var picH = 2;
    var imageElement = document.getElementById("theIDofTheImage");
    imageElement.height = picH;
</script>
```

Of course I'm sure you're doing something a little more complicated but I wanted to just give a simplistic answer to your question.

Cheers!

~JI

Comment: Shouldn't your script be at the end of your body so it can actually detect the image ?

Comment: Yep. I'm a bit rusty, have been writing driver software lately and was using jQuery's ready function previously. I suppose ultimately I like to see all javascript included in the head tag as a separate file.... Again, this was intended as a simplistic answer. Gave much more than was given. Thank you.