# HTML Setting <img height> equal to a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am working on a sharepoint app which primarily uses javascript. I have the user being able to set a variable by choice which I am trying to use as the width of an image on screen.

The value is stored as `SizeVal` in the same `<script>` tag and I would like to be able to use this variable as the width/height of an image

Can I use that to create something which reflects the meaning of:

```
<img src="example.png" width=SizeVal height=SizeVal>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is "the basics of JS DOM manipulation". A few years ago I'd have simply replied "use jQuery" :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript

Comment: Gerardo - I had already looked at that but the image is pulled from a URL and I do not have direct access to the document

Comment: @Christopher create the image in JS, add it to the DOM with the SizeVal ?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to modify the images size after setting the value, for example:

html

```
<input type="text" id="myInp" />

<img id="myImg" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" width="0px" height="0px">
```

js

```
(function() {
  document.getElementById("myInp").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById('myImg').setAttribute('width', this.value);
    document.getElementById('myImg').setAttribute('height', this.value);
  });
})();
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maxidelo/8b6p33wm/)

Or you can use a framework like AngularJS or https://mustache.github.io/ to do something like this ..

```
<img src="example.png" width="{{SizeVal}}" height="{{SizeVal}}">
```