# Not able to change height and width of image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I am trying to change the height and width of image which I read from the input and trying to display it back, this the code:

```
function readanddisplayImage(input){
  if(input.files && input.files[0]){         
     var filereader = new FileReader(); 
     filereader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);         
     filereader.onload = function(reader){
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = reader.target.result;     
            image.width = 150;
            image.height = 150;       
            //It works fine till this line but in the next line image is displayed without the size changed. 
            $("#profilePicture").css("background-image", "url('" + image.src + "')");             
            alert(image.width +"  "+ image.height);
     }
  }    
}
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?? ThankYou.

Comment: try to replace image.width with image.style.width 
and replace image.height with image.style.height

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript

Comment: @MdMusfekurRahman - that doesn't effect the image when used as a css background either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changing the image width and height like that wont effect the image when used as a CSS background ... try changing the backgound image dimensions using CSS

```
 filereader.onload = function(reader){
        $("#profilePicture").css("background-image", "url('" + reader.target.result + "')").css("background-size", "150px 150px");

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really hekpfull

Answer (score 0):

A background image's size is managed by the CSS property `background-size` - for example, set it to `150px 150px` for the desired effect.