# Enlarging an image using javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used javascript to create an onclick button to change the items' image according to its colour. However, the new image followed the width and height of the original image after clicking the button. Is there a way to enlarge the image after clicking on the button?

These are my html, css and javascript codes.

```js
function change1() {
  eyeliner1.src = "https://s5.postimg.org/lj0ifekvr/Tattoo_Liner.png";
}

function change2() {
  eyeliner1.src = "https://s5.postimg.org/6lllv5mif/Tattoo_Liner_Mad_Max_Brown.png";
}
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}
.buttondeco {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #888;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="eye">
  <img class="center" src="https://s5.postimg.org/lj0ifekvr/Tattoo_Liner.png" id="eyeliner1" alt="Tattoo Liner" height="300" width="119">
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buttondeco" style="text-align:center; background-color: #000;" id="size" onclick="change1()"></button>
    <button class="buttondeco" style="text-align:center; background-color: #644741;" onclick="change2()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the inline width/height parameters on your <img> (`height="300" width="119"`) to let the image size itself.

Comment: @JonUleis Thank you for your answer, however i needed to resize the image because the original image size is quite large. Is there a way to change the image size using codes?

Comment: As Jon says you should remove the inline width/height parameters. Then you can use javascript to set the CSS height/width parameters of the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image size with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

Comment: @JerlynTan `#eye { width: /* desired pxs */ } #eye img{ width: 100% }` will do the work.

Comment: You can also use javascript to remove the inline width/height parameters ...

Comment: @ADyson sorry, im quite new to javascript. Could you give me an example on how to change the width/height using javascript?

Comment: check out the duplicate I flagged in the comment above, the code is all there (and in about 200 other places on the web :-) )

Comment: @Adyson sure, i already checked it and it didn't work and so does the other 200 places(nice estimates by the way).

Comment: define "didn't work"? you did `eyeliner1.style.height = "200px"`? And you removed the inline height/width attributes from the HTML? And ensured that the "eye" div doesn't have any height/width rules that would constrain it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Give your desired width and height accordingly

```js
function change1() {
  eyeliner1.src = "https://s5.postimg.org/lj0ifekvr/Tattoo_Liner.png";
  eyeliner1.height="500"; //Your desired Height
  eyeliner1.width="219"; //Your desired Width
}

function change2() {
  eyeliner1.src = "https://s5.postimg.org/6lllv5mif/Tattoo_Liner_Mad_Max_Brown.png";
  eyeliner1.height="700";  //Your desired Height
  eyeliner1.width="419"; //Your desired Width
}
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}
.buttondeco {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #888;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="eye">
  <img class="center" src="https://s5.postimg.org/lj0ifekvr/Tattoo_Liner.png" id="eyeliner1" alt="Tattoo Liner" height="300" width="119">
  <div class="button">
    <button class="buttondeco" style="text-align:center; background-color: #000;" id="size" onclick="change1()"></button>
    <button class="buttondeco" style="text-align:center; background-color: #644741;" onclick="change2()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must find which one of width or height of the new image is closer to the original image. After changing src:

```
$('#eyeliner1').removeAttr('width');
$('#eyeliner1').removeAttr('height');
var newWidth = $('#eyeliner1').width();
var newHeight = $('#eyeliner1').height();
var widthIsCloserThanHeight = parseFloat(119/newWidth) > parseFloat(300/newHeight);

if(widthIsCloserThanHeight) 
    $('#eyeliner1').css('width', '119px').css('height', 'auto');
else
    $('#eyeliner1').css('width', 'auto').css('height', '300px');
```

As you said the image is very large and this code only works when new image original size is larger than 119px/300px.