# Set picture width to proportional size

Tags: javascript

Imagine that you have an image

```
<img id="imgid" height="15" width="149" src="image.png" alt="[]" />
```

and you want to change its dimensions to `height="30"` and width to proportional size.  The first part is easy:

```
document.getElementById('imgid').height=30px;
```

However, wat about the second part?  Is it possible to do something similar to

```
document.getElementById('imgid').width='auto';
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You should get the current height, find out the ratio of it compared to target height, then apply the same ratio to get the new width. Example: if current height is 15 then ratio is 30/15 = 2... so new width is old width * 2

Comment: Afaik that should work. Can you try it out? If not, you could always first get the width and do width = new height / old height * current width

Comment: chech this link out [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984053/3652823) as it answeres your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the css properties instead (included both jQuery and plain JS solutions):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#resize").click(function() {
    $("#test").css("width", "100px");
    $("#test").css("height", "auto");
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    function resizeImg() {
      var el = document.getElementById("test")
      el.style.width = "200px"
      el.style.height = "auto"
    }
  </script>
  <img id="test" src="https://media.licdn.com/media/p/8/000/1e9/0e5/26e178f.png" width="323" height="110">
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="resize">Resize jQuery</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="resizeImg()">Resize plain JS</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

> **width**
>
> The intrinsic width of the image in pixels. In HTML 4, either a
>   percentage or pixels were acceptable values. In HTML5, however, only
>   pixels are acceptable.

Use `style` properties instead

```
document.getElementById('imgid').style.height="30px";
document.getElementById('imgid').style.width='auto';
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `style.height` and `style.width`. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
document.getElementById('imgid').style.height = '90px';
document.getElementById('imgid').style.width = 'auto';
```

```html
<img id="imgid" height="180" width="240" src="https://www.joomlack.fr/images/demos/demo2.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem if I understand correct your problem:

```
img {
  max-height: 30px;
  width: auto;
}
```