# Update two images separately

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have two images show together when I'm trying to update one image nothing happened I want to be able to update one image and the second stay the same

Controller.cs

```
 public ActionResult Edit(MainSections mainSections, HttpPostedFileBase file , HttpPostedFileBase file2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var mainInDb = db.MainSections.Find(mainSections.MainID);
            if (file != null)
            {
                string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                mainInDb.Img = ImageName;
            }
            if (file != null)
            {
                string ImageName2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file2.FileName);
                string physicalPath2 = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName2);

               file2.SaveAs(physicalPath2);
                mainInDb.smallImg = ImageName2;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(mainSections);
    }
```

Edit.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MainSections", FormMethod.Post,
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))


            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  /> 

            <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"  />
```

Comment: Shouldn't your second `if (file != null)` be `if (file2 != null)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Peter B seems to be right and the second one should be if (file2 != null).

Second, as i see each file contain an image and each file has a unique id so you can access the Needed image in the Needed file using the file id, then you can change whatever you want and it would only affect one image.
(for example: In your view add a Javascript function that can make the changes you want...check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297456/6653133)