# How do I set default height and width to data coming from ckeditor (wysiwyg text editor) while displaying in the website through php

Tags: php, ckeditor, html-entities

I am using the CKEditor as a text editor for my project and I am also uploading images in there. I could have saved the default height and width of the editor before inserting the data into the database, however, in order to have a fit-in screen for the Android and iOS, I have to set null value in the height and width in the preview box. And for the website before fetching the data I am using `html_entity_decode`. Everything works perfectly fine with `html_entity_decode` but the size of the image is ruining my webpage. Is there any way I can deal with the images coming to the CKEditor while displaying content on the website?

For the website, I want to set the default height to 500px and width to 900px.

I am getting data like this without html_entity_decode:

> दूतावासले नेपाली कामदार कार्यरत कम्पनी र बिमा कम्पनीविरुद्ध मुद्दा लडेर क्षतिपूर्ति रकम उपलब्ध गराएको हो । ‘कुवेती कानुनले दिएको अधिकार प्रयोग गरी हामीले मुद्दा लडेर क्षतिपूर्ति दिलाइएको हो,’ राजदूत यज्ञबहादुर हमालले कान्तिपुरलाई भने, ‘घाइते र मृत्यु भएका श्रमिकका परिवारका तर्फबाट मुद्दा लडेका हौं ।’
>
> `<p><img alt="" src="/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/sher_bahadur_deuba_X4KLNxAc7l.JPG" /></p>`
>
> दूतावासले मुद्दा लड्न कुवेती वकिललाई प्रयोग गरेको हो । राजदूत हमालले प्रमाण भएमा उच्च क्षतिपूर्ति दिलाउन सकिने बताए । एउटै ब्यक्तिलाई ६४ हजार अमेरिकी डलरसम्म क्षतिपूर्ति दिलाइएको र सबैभन्दा बढी कार्यस्थल र सडक दुर्घटनामा मृत्यु हुने श्रमिकका परिवारले पाएका दूतावासले जनाएको छ । ‘

Is it possible to replace it with str_replace/css/js?

I have following lines of code in the file where I am not being able to set width and height of img tag:

```
<?php require 'inc/header.php';
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id) {
    $getNews = $news->getNewsById($id);
}
if ($getNews) {

    $content = $getNews[0]->story;

    $content = str_replace('<img ', '<img width="900" height="500" ', $content);

    print_r($content); 

    exit;
}

}
 ?>

<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- End of top adspace -->
        <div class="row py-2 px-2">

            <!--  Main Content Column-->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h1 class="py-3 text-md-center" style="margin: auto;"><?php echo $getNews[0]->title ?>
                </h1>
                <?php 

                $image = basename($getNews[0]->image);

                if (isset($getNews[0]->image) && !empty($getNews[0]->image) && file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR.'news/'.$image)) {

                    $feature = UPLOAD_URL.'news/'.$image; 
                ?>
                <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $feature ?>" class="img-fluid py-2 apple" style="width:900px; height: 600px"></a>
                <?php

                } else {
                    $feature = "";
                    ?>
                    <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $feature ?>" class="img-fluid py-2 apple"></a>
                    <?php
                }

                 ?>
                <p class="ptype777 editor">
                    <?php echo html_entity_decode($getNews[0]->story) ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-8 col-md-8 pt-2">
                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 55px">

                        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo FRONT_IMAGES_URL ?>template2.gif" alt="template1" class="img-fluid pt-4 apple"></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo FRONT_IMAGES_URL ?>template3.gif" alt="template1" class="img-fluid py-2 apple"></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo FRONT_IMAGES_URL ?>template4.gif" alt="template1" class="img-fluid py-2 apple"></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo FRONT_IMAGES_URL ?>template5.gif" alt="template1" class="img-fluid py-2 apple"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @andy I appreciate your help but how can I do that?

Comment: I removed my comment and changed it to an answer.

Comment: @andy I have modified my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to either define the dimensions in CSS or use javascript to set the dimensions.

**CSS option:**

```
img {
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

**Javascript option**
[Change image size with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

**Another option is to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).**

```
str_replace('<img ', '<img width="900" height="500" ', $content);
```

In the above scenario I assume that $content contains the Image tags you want to set the width and height to.

Comment: CSS, str_replace did not work and I wouldn't know the id so I don't think I can do it with JavaScript

Comment: You don't need the ID. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp. And did you try $content = str_replace('<img ', '<img width="900" height="500" ', $content); or did you just do the str_replace?

Comment: I tried with $content = str_replace('<img ', '<img width="900" height="500" ', $content); or did you just do the str_replace?. None of the above seems to work.

Comment: $content = "<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/assets/editor/kcfinder/upload/images/sher_bahadur_deuba_X4KLNxAc7l.JPG\" /></p>";
        print_r(str_replace('<img ', '<img width="900" height="500" ', $content)); exit; This will print your image in your browser with the width and height tag. I tried it myself and I know it works. If it doesn't work for you, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: can we chat in StackOverflow?