# How to set image height within script

Tags: css, image, tags, resize

I'm currently trying to create a banner that displays random images on each refresh. I've managed to get that working but I need to change the height of the images to 139px, rather than have them displayed at full size.
How can I set the height of the images within the script that loads the images at random?

I learnt code 15 years ago at school, so my understanding of it now is basically 0, so I'm easily lost! There is probably a better way of loading random images to start with, but this was the only one I've been able to get to work.

```html
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:1072;height:139px;overflow:hidden;" class="banner3"></div>

<script>
      var randomImage = {
        paths: [
          "c1.png",
          "c2.png",
          "c3.png",
    "c4.png",
    "c5.png",
    "c6.png",
    "c7.png",
        ],
        generate: function(){
          var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = path;
          $("div.banner3").html(img);

        }
      }
      randomImage.generate();
  
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image size with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use document.createElement instead of image, like this:

```
var randomImage = {
    paths: [
      "c1.png",
      "c2.png",
      "c3.png",
      "c4.png",
      "c5.png",
      "c6.png",
      "c7.png",
    ],
    generate: function(){
      var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = path;

      img.height = DESIRED HEIGHT

      $("div.banner3").html(img);

    }
  }
  randomImage.generate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];
var img = new Image();
img.src = path;
```

After this you can add:

```
img.style.height = '139px';
```

And then set it to html:

```
$("div.banner3").html(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in CSS:

```js
var randomImage = {
  paths: [ "https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/300",
          "https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/300",
          "https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/300",
          "https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/300",
          "https://picsum.photos/id/5/300/300",
          "https://picsum.photos/id/6/300/300",
          "https://picsum.photos/id/7/300/300" ],
  generate: function(){
    var path = randomImage.paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.paths.length)];
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = path;
    $("div.banner3").html(img);
  }
}

randomImage.generate();
```

```css
.banner3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 139px;
  overflow: hidden
}
.banner3 img {
  height: 139px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner3"></div>
```