# Changing the size of an image within the script?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So I'm trying to do an onclick image change which worked, but I'd like the second image to be bigger than the first, is this possible?

Here is the JavaScript code (this is the first time I'm trying to use HTML aside from basic things)

```
function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://cdn.glitch.com/2191cc92-26e9-4b6e-9beb-428fb7eb3976%2FPicsArt_03-26-03.26.33.png?v=1616763476562") 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://cdn.glitch.com/2191cc92-26e9-4b6e-9beb-428fb7eb3976%2FPicsArt_03-26-03.12.37.png?v=1616764012012";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://cdn.glitch.com/2191cc92-26e9-4b6e-9beb-428fb7eb3976%2FPicsArt_03-26-03.26.33.png?v=1616763476562";
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to change the size of that second image.

Comment: Do you want to change the width/height of the image or use a completely different image (different link)?

Comment: set the element's width and height

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change image size with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

To change the width and/or height of the image simply use the style property like this:

```
const myImage = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange")

myImage.style.width = '500px'
myImage.style.height = '600px'
```