# How to change the width of an image inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

index.html (I don't have access to this, I just load it using ajax from the database)

```
<img src="" width=100>
```

How will I be able to call that in my javascript file? I have tried using the

```
iFrame.contents().find("img").css({ "max-width": "50%", "max-height": "50%" });
```

but upon checking the inspect button the html file just became

```
<img src="" width=100 style="max-width": "50%", "max-height": "50%">
```

Are there any approach on how to change just the width but not add a css on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript

Comment: `I don't have access to this`; is it part of your app? If not, you likely can't adjust it due to cross-site-scripting concerns.